# Имитация поля autoincrement

Tags: oracle, sql

Я знаю, что в Oracle нет возможности добавить для поля `autoincrement`, но знаю один способ, как это сымитировать.

Кто еще знает? Чем больше вариантов, тем интереснее.

Вот тот, что я знаю:

```
create table test(id number);

/* sequence - это объект базы данных, 
который генерирует целые числа в соответствии с 
правилами, установленными во время его создания. */
create sequence test_sq start with 1;

/* Получить следуйщий id */
insert into test values(test_sq.nextval);
commit;
```

Answer (score 3):

Однозначно только сиквенс, вариант с max 100% вызовет проблему при работе нескольких пользователей. не посчитайте "троллем" но max не будет использовать ни один человек который хотя бы сколько то проработал с Oracle

Answer (score 3):

Начиная с 12c (12.1.0.1 06/2013) появилась [*identity column*](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAHJHJC) (=*auto-increment*):

```
create table items (id number generated always as identity primary key, name varchar2 (32));
```

До этого, кроме широко известного решения с генераторами последовательностей (*sequences*), можно было в качестве сурогатных ключей использовать UUID:

```
create table items (id raw (16) default sys_guid (), name varchar2 (32));
```

, что давало экономию места 8 байт (~33%) на само поле и на индекс по сравнению с `NUMBER`.

Для попробовать:

```
insert into items (name) select 'item '||rownum from xmlTable ('1 to 3');
select * from items;

        ID NAME                            
---------- ----------
         1 item 1                          
         2 item 2                          
         3 item 3    

ID                               NAME                            
-------------------------------- ----------
849AD5F2914564AAE0530A01A8C08076 item 1                          
849AD5F2914664AAE0530A01A8C08076 item 2                          
849AD5F2914764AAE0530A01A8C08076 item 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Иногда интересно решение со строго возрастающей последовательностью, которая видна и уникальна только для текущей сессии. Например, подготовка данных для вставки в целевые таблицы, в которых используется другое решение для обеспечения уникальности.

С переменными сессии это реализуется очень просто:

```
create or replace package common as
    function nextSeq return number;
end;
/
create or replace package body common as
    seq_ number;
    function nextSeq return number is
    begin
        seq_ := seq_ + 1;
        return (seq_);
    end;
begin seq_ := 0;
end;
/
```

Конечно, использовать имеет смысл только во временных таблицах:

```
create global temporary table mytmptab (id number primary key, name varchar2 (32)) on commit preserve rows
;

insert into mytmptab 
    select common.nextSeq id, t.column_value.getClobVal () name
    from xmlTable ('"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"') t
    ;
select * from mytmptab;

        ID NAME                            
---------- --------------------------------
         1 aaa                             
         2 bbb                             
         3 ccc
```

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с сиквенсом самый лучший, потому что нативный.

Вариант с max() - медленный и не обеспечивает уникальности сгенерённого ключа.

Вариант с триггером - будут потери на переключение контекста между sql машиной и pl/sql машиной. Кроме того триггер будет срабатывать при загрузке данных sql-loader-ом или любой другой вставке с уже существующим идшником.

Comment: Ох накаляете) хорошо та как, а что с max() не так?

Comment: Проведите эксперимент. 1 сессия. select max() + 1, а потом insert и НЕ КОММИТЕТЬ. 2 сессия - select max()+1. Что получите? Правильно. В двух сессиях одинаковые ключи. Ну и кроме того select - это запрос к таблице, а взятие nextval - это обращение к кэшу значений сиквенса.

Comment: Я же щас проверю. ))

Comment: Что-то не вяжется, ты такой пример имел веду?
(перед коммитом я проверил в веб интерфейсе, там добавленной строки еще не было)

SQL> select max(id)+1 from animal;

 MAX(ID)+1
----------
  6

SQL> insert into animal (id, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME) values (6, 'test', 'test');

1 row created.

SQL> select max(id)+1 from animal;                                       

 MAX(ID)+1
----------
  7

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select max(id)+1 from animal;

 MAX(ID)+1
----------
  7

Comment: Капитан Очевидномсть mode on. Второй select max(id)+1 from animal надо делать во второй сессии до того, как сделал commit в первой. Капитан Очевидномсть mode off.

Comment: Да ежу понятно, что с сиквенсом самый лучший вариант. Человек попросил побольше вариантов или вы читаете вопрос слово через слово? :)

Comment: @AndrewFrolov мои действия были такие, я сначало определил max()+1 = 6  -> потом добавил запись -> потом опять определил max()+1 = 7 -> потом закоммител => определил max()+1 = 7

Comment: @jmu До человека сразу дошло, что азарта хочется)

Comment: Я понял какие были твои действия. Они не верны. Повторюсь ещё раз - проблема будет в мультитрединге, в твоём эксперименте его нет. открой ДВЕ КОНСОЛИ к базе и внимательно перечитай что я писал.

Comment: Ок, попробую) может и правда сглупил, еще интереснее стало, а вы работаете с Oraclоm?

Comment: Сейчас - нет. До этого 6 лет работал.

Comment: Все Гуру для меня, надо вас запомнить.)

Answer (score 0):

```
-- подходит в случае маленьких транзакций 
-- (да это небезопасно! да это долго, да это еще 1 вариант )
select nvl (max(tt.id)+1, 0) from test tt;

-- тоже самое с использованием триггера
-- (да это небезопасно! да это долго, да это еще 1 вариант )   
create or replace trigger test_autoincrement 
before insert on test
for each row
begin
   select nvl (max(tt.id)+1, 0) into :new.id from test tt;
end;

-- триггер с использованием sequence (имхо наиболее оптимальный выбор)
create or replace trigger test_autoincrement 
before insert on test
for each row
begin
   select test_sq.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end;
```

**UP1**: исправил запросы

Comment: Кавабунга))) я думал тут  все профи на Oracle, и что даже не смотрят такие "простые вопросы",
СПАСИБО, не дал теме загнуться, буду сидеть теперь и наслаждаться твоими вкусными примерчики))))))

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL и другие базы используют очень удобный способ автоникремента. Чаще всего его применяют для ключевых полей таблицы. Первоначально в Oracle не было автоинкремента, но позднее в версии 12 (выпуск 2015 года), автоинкремент появился. 
Вот статья, котрая описывает [оба подхода](https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=oracle-autoincrement).

Я расскажу, как можно использовать sequence для генерации нового значения ключа. Этот хороший способ для демонстрации того, что представляет собой структура sequnce, и как создавать простые триггеры. 
При вставке нового значения (оператор insert) можно использовать построчный триггер на таблице (before insert for each row). В примере ниже таблица называется demo, ключевое поле demo.id. Тип этого поля можно выбрать произвольно (integer, varchar2 и т.д.). Обычно выбирают тип integer. Поскольку поле является ключом, для него добавляют ограничение уникальности и ограничение not null.

```
CREATE TABLE demo_table
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
[...]
CONSTRAINT demo_id_unique UNIQUE (id)
);

create sequence sq_demo_id start with 1;

create or replace trigger TRG_DEMO_INSERTS 
before insert on demo_table
for each row
begin
   select sq_demo_id.nextval into :new.id from dual;
end
```

Здесь sq_demo_id - счетчик, sequence c автоматическим увеличением на единицу при каждом вызове. Если нужно будет узнать текущее значение счетчика, то используйте 
sq_demo_id.curval.
Создание тригера является однократным действием. Не нужно заботиться о конфликтах с параллелными сеансами, эта проблема устраняется в триггере. 
Новый подход, создание счетчика через оператор identity ещё больше облегчает жизнь программистам.

```
CREATE TABLE demo_table
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 
1),
[...] UNIQUE (id)
)
```

При его реализации похожие структуры создаются автоматически, самим ядром PL/SQL. Они обладают меньшей гибкостью в настройках, но код становится легче, его проще поддерживать.

Comment: Тема нескколько устарела, автоинкримент уже давно есть. Второй вариант я бы не рекомендовал, он даже не во всех случаях будет работать.

Comment: 0xdb, спасибо за подсказку. Действительно, с начиная с 12 версии (релиз 2014 года ) появился автоинкремент. Вот здесь описан пример: https://www.dmosk.ru/miniinstruktions.php?mini=oracle-autoincrement.  Ссылка на документацию: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402.

Answer (score 0):

В Oracle 12c и выше можно сделать что-то подобное:

```
--create table
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
   ID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
   CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY(ID),
   CONSTRAINT UK_TEST UNIQUE(ID)
);
```

До Oracle 12с:

```
--create table
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
   ID INTEGER,
   CONSTRAINT PK_TEST PRIMARY KEY(ID),
   CONSTRAINT UK_TEST UNIQUE(ID)
);

--create sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_SEQ;

--create tigger using the sequence
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TEST_TRG 
  BEFORE INSERT ON TEST
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.ID IS NULL)
  BEGIN
  SELECT TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL
    INTO :new.ID
    FROM DUAL;
END;
```